# Equation for reversible adiabatic expansion

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility, adiabatic

The heat capacity of one mole of an ideal gas is found to be $C_{v}=3R(1+aRT)/2$ where $a$ is a constant. The book provides the solution to this problem but there is a step in which $(1+aRT)=e^{aRt}$ How is this possible?
Please explain.

Comment: I'm guessing you are given $nC_vdT=n\frac{3}{2}R(1+aRT)dT=-PdV=-\frac{nRT}{V}dV$.  Correct?

Comment: ${}$ Which book?

Comment: The equation you are asking about is an approximation.  If you expand $e^{aRT}$ in a Taylor series about aRT=0, the first two terms are 1 + aRT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $aRT$ is extremely small then $$e^{aRT} \approx 1+aRT$$